# <Form:Errors /> Not Showing Any Errors

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm not seeing any error messages in my SpringMVC form after submission when there are field errors. **I verified that errors exist in the Errors object.**

From reading some other threads, this occurs because I'm redirecting to a new ModelAndView, and somehow losing my request attributes? I couldn't figure out a solution from reading related threads. I tried returning a String with just the view, and making the method String-based, but that fails.

```
public ModelAndView save(final HttpServletRequest request, 
                               @ModelAttribute Model model, 
                               BindingResult bindingResult) {


    ModelValidator.validate(model, bindingResult);

    if (!bindingResult.hasErrors()){          
        // Save
        // etc.
    }         

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("myform.jsp", "model", model);                                        
    return mav;
}
```

JSP:

```
    <form:form method="POST" commandName="model" action="/save">            

          <%--  SpringMVC Error Div --%>
          <form:errors />
     </form:form>
```

Errors exist but are not shown in the result.

Comment: Try with `<form:errors path="*" />`

Comment: That doesn't work either. It's a question of losing my request attributes somehow, or redirecting to a new MaV.